# C# : How to handle method that is implemented in derived classes but not in the parent class in a loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, inheritance

I have the following method in my class:

```
    public double ComputeCost()
    {
        double Cost = 0;
        foreach (GenericTask Task in this.GenericTasks){
            Cost += Task.Compute();
        }

        return Cost;
        
    }
```

The issue is that the `Compute` method is only implemented in derived classes from `GenericTask` e.g. `EngineeringTask` and `DevelopmentTask` and therefore the above code does not compile.

How can I achieve what I want? I am new to C# and does not know the "clean way" to achieve this ? Shall I implement a dummy `Compute` method in the `GenericTasks` altough it will never compute anything because it lacks proper data ?

Comment: Please do not name a variable `Task` with an uppercase T. That symbol represents a type that gets very common use.

Comment: Where can I find proper syntax ´rules’ ? In python there is the PEP. Is there an equivalent for C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an abstract method in the base class and have the derived classes override that method.

Base class:

```
public abstract double Compute();
```

Derived class:

```
public override double Compute()
{
    /* your class-specific implementation */
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Comment: In addition to what @Moho said, you can read more about Polymorphism and Overriding to comprehend OOP concepts.